# jQuery find last input and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an image after the last input field in a div, any ideas as to why this won't work?

```
$('<img src="img/loading.gif" id="loading_img" />').appendTo($(form).find('input:last'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("<img/>", {
  src:  "img/loading.gif",
  id:   "loading_img"
}).insertAfter($("form").find("input:last"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the insertAfter function:

```
$('<img src="img/loading.gif" id="loading_img" />').insertAfter($("form").find('input:last'));
```

The append function adds the image INTO the input with insertAfter you insert the image AFTER the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<img src="img/loading.gif" id="loading_img" />').appendTo('#formid-here input:last'));
```