# appendTo Find the last input jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, clone, appendto

**Notice:** Before starting to explain, just let me point this out: This isn't a duplicated topic, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591002/jquery-find-last-input-and-append) is about insertAfter, not appendTo, and I still couldn't make it.

**What's the deal?**

When I click on Radio Button it clones a paragraph containing 1 input type text, 1 input type radio and 2 buttons (1 to add, and the other to remove the whole paragraph)
Can you guys help me making this add button working?

**What's supposed to do?** It's supposed to add 1 radio immediately after the first input radio of it's paragraph

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nFdJE/) Thank you [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny)

Ok, here's the thing

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="teste">

<!--Input text-->
<p class="text"><br><input type="text" placeholder="Question Name"><br><input type="text" value="User Answer" disabled><button onclick="remove_element(this)">Remove</button></p>

<!--Input date-->
<p class="date"><br><input type="text" placeholder="Question Name"><br><input type="date" disabled><button onclick="remove_element(this)">Remove</button></p>

<!--Input Radio-->
<p class="radio"><br><input type="text" placeholder="Question Name"><br><input class="radio_option" type="radio"><input type="text"><button onclick="addOption(this)">+</button><br><button onclick="remove_element(this)">Remove</button></p>

<p>Select a field to add</p>
<button type="text" class="addtext" onclick="addElement(this)">Textbox</button>
<button type="date" class="adddate" onclick="addElement(this)">Date</button>
<button type="radio" class="addradio" onclick="addElement(this)">Radio Button</button>

<div id="create_form"></div>
```

**Style**

```
<style>
.teste{
    display:none;
}

.text{
    display:none;
}

.date{
    display:none;
}

.radio{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

*It's just setting its display to hide it*

**jQuery**

```
function addElement(element){
var type = $(element).attr("type");
$("."+ type + ":first").clone().appendTo("#create_form");
$("."+ type + ":last").toggle();
};  

function remove_element(input){
     $(input).parent().remove();
};

function addOption(element){
    $(".teste:first").clone().appendTo($(element).parent().find("input:last"));
    $(".teste:last").toggle();
};
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nFdJE/2/ ?

Comment: Yes thank you, can you tell me what did you change? Though, I intended to add 1 radio button after the previous one of it's paragraph each time I click on the plus button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle for you that works and added the click handlers for the script:

```
$('.addtext, .adddate, .addradio').click(function() {
   addElement($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2AwP/4/

Comment: I wasn't clear about what I really intended to do. I mean to add 1 radio button after the previous one of it's paragraph each time I click on the plus button

Comment: Radio button only or also the field?

Comment: Thank you for your support. Radio button with the input text next to it ;) Still, I guess I can manage with the radio button only :p

Comment: I think this is it, it's not clean yet, but it works!

Comment: It does :D Thank you man ;) When there is another paragraph with radios it clones more than one, but I think I can fix it ;)