# how to dynamically add input elements one below the other in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have following code. The input textboxes are getting generated. Only the thing is i wanted them to be added one below  the other. Here is my code:

```
$('.pl').on('click',function(){

        var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
        var hiddenButton = document.createElement("button");
        var hiddenTextNode = document.createTextNode("Delete");

        $(this).after(hiddenInput);
        hiddenButton.appendChild(hiddenTextNode);
        $(this).after(hiddenButton);
        $(this).write("<p>hi</p>");
        c=c+1; 
        document.getElementById("h").value = c;

        hiddenInput.name = 'text'+c;
        hiddenInput.class = 'form-control add-polls-container';
        hiddenInput.placeholder = 'Enter Poll Option';

    });
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or describe your problem more clearer.

Comment: I have 1 button- "Add more". When I click on "Add more" button i wanted a new textbox should appear along with a "Delete button". This code works as expected. But the textbox is getting added on the same line horizontally. I wanted the dynamic textboes to appear one below the other. How  to achieve this?

Comment: Wrap all the elements in `<div>`

Comment: Wrap each textbox with"Delete button" into `div` tag. Something like `<div><input type="text" /><input type="button" /></div>`

Comment: how to wrap it? I have used  $(this).afte() method.

Answer (score 0):

you just refer

[jQuery find last input and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591002/jquery-find-last-input-and-append)

$(this).after(hiddenInput); Here $(this) means click bind element so its append textbox to click element

Comment: Just find the last textbox or delete button in that form and append to new one

Comment: i tried using find() to get the last inserted textbox. But now my dynamic textbox is getting added after the search textbox in my menubar.